# Flattening nested lists comparison

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'd like to understand the diferences on the both code results for flattening a nested list in python or pythonic. Maybe I'm doing a mistake on pythonic code but, if I am not, Can anybody explain the the difference on the results? code below:

````
nested_list = [['rodrigo'],['fernanda','lorena','marcela'],['carolina'],['marcio','cristina','patricia','regina']]

# Regular programing
flat_list = []
for list in nested_list:
    for element in list:
        flat_list.append(element)
print(flat_list)
# Results: ['rodrigo', 'fernanda', 'lorena', 'marcela', 'carolina', 'marcio', 'cristina', 'patricia', 'regina']


# Pythonic
flat_list = [element for element in list for list in nested_list]
print(flat_list)
# Results: ['marcio', 'marcio', 'marcio', 'marcio', 'cristina', 'cristina', 'cristina', 'cristina', 'patricia', \
#    'patricia', 'patricia', 'patricia', 'regina', 'regina', 'regina', 'regina']```
````

Comment: The second is in the wrong order and doesn't cause that output unless I'm missing something. If that were corrected though, they're the same. The latter just has implicit `append`ing.

Comment: If this code actually runs for you and produces that output, I believe you have a `list` variable already in scope with data that's messing with your results.

Comment: This is what the second one should look like `[element for sublist in nested_list for element in sublist]`. And this is indeed called [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). It does the same, just shorter syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code works without error by "accident" because you continue with the name `list` as it was defined in your first solution, and so it represents the *last* row of the input.

It is actually doing this:

```
flat_list = []
for element in list:
    for list in nested_list:
        flat_list.append(element)
print(flat_list)
```

If you would change `list` to `mylist` (a name that was not already used), you would see that both your code, and this explanatory code would run into an error.

Your second solution should really do this in the opposite order:

```
flat_list = [element for lst in nested_list for element in lst]
```

Also, it is not such a good idea to use a name that is already used by Python (`list`).

Comment: Thanks you all.  It was my mistake. I'll review the list comprehension with free variables to do not commit the same mistake on my trials.